# Unexpected PHP version 5.5.15rc1 from ppa:ondrej/php5

Tags: 12.04, php

I've just upgraded from Ondrej's oldstable 5.4 to 5.5 package on 12.04 - which was smooth.

The version installed is 5.5.15rc - I wasn't expecting the rc bit.

Will an upgrade regularly include RC versions and is there a way to stick to the official releases - currently at 5.5.14 - without hand-picking upgrades?

Comment: As a side note - I just have no clue, why you are asking this question here and not via the issue tracker I have set up or the contact form for the PPA.  Also my email isn't that hard to find.  You are just lucky I have a notifications on PHP here and I read it tonight (that's also something you can't count on).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your questions - there's a crasher bug in locale setting when locale is empty, thus the emergency upgrade to RC1.   It might happen from time to time when I see a strong reason for the upgrade to the RC version.